# Unity SetActive(true) not working for panel

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

So I have a finishMenu that I'd like to activate when the player finishes the level. I have a UI container (canvas) that contains among other things, my finishMenu. When colliding with a finish pad, the player script executes EndLevel(). It executes a lot of stuff, but it also calls the Finish() function on my UI container:

```
public void Finish()
{
    Debug.Log("Finish Called!");
    finishMenu.SetActive(true);
    Debug.Log("self: " + finishMenu.activeSelf + " hierarchy: " + finishMenu.activeInHierarchy);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
}
```

this is supposed to set it to active, and I'm not getting any errors. The second Debug.Log tells me that finishMenu is activeSelf but not activeInHierarchy, even though the parent gameObject (UI container) is active...

[image: Hierarchy]

I have assigned finishMenu in the inspector, so I don't know what to do...

I have tried debugging with the Debug.Logs and breakpoints, and searching through my code to see if something is setting it to inactive, but I haven't found the answer yet. The finishMenu is supposed to activate, but it doesn't activate.

Comment: You've cropped this screenshot so tight that we can't see what's above or around it. Can you walk us through the steps needed to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem?